# SwiftUI table of elements using List - scrolling

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui

I'm trying to present a large table of data (more than 100 rows by 100 columns). I'm holding the data in a two dimensional array:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PivotCell : Hashable {
    enum CellType {
        case columnHeader, rowHeader, value, total, grandTotal, blank
    }

    let id = UUID()
    let cellType : CellType
    let contents : String

    static func == (lhs: PivotCell, rhs: PivotCell) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    init(cellType: PivotCell.CellType, contents: String ) {
        self.cellType = cellType
        self.contents = contents
    }
}

struct PivotTableView: View {
    var displayData : [[PivotCell]]

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List(self.displayData, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(row, id: \.id) { cell  in
                        PivotCellView(cell)
                    }
                }
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height).id(UUID())
        }
    }
}

struct PivotCellView: View {
    let cell: PivotCell

    var body: some View {
        Text(cell.contents)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 30, alignment: .center)
    }

    init(_ cell: PivotCell) {
        self.cell = cell
    }
}



struct PivotTableView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static  var cell = PivotCell(cellType: .value, contents: "123")
    static var displayData = [[cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell],
        [cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell, cell]]

    static var previews: some View {
        PivotTableView(displayData: displayData)
    }
}
```

I've tried to:

1. wrap it in a ScrollView(.horizontal) – it disappears
2. use VStack in stead of List, within the ScrollView(.horizontal) – it
       works but performance is lousy, as we don't benefit from List's cell
       reuse

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: can you show us your PivotDisplaycell so we can try out?

Comment: Yes - sorry, forgot to include...done. Thanks